# Create a cumulated sum between a range of rows

Tags: python, pandas

- First column **cond** contains either 1 or 0
- Second column **event** contains either 1 or 0
- I want to create a third column where each row is the (cumulated sum of cond  % 4) of the COND column between two rows where event==1 (first row where event==1 must be included in the cumulated sum but not the last row)

```
+------+-------+--------+
| cond | event | Result |
+------+-------+--------+
| 0    | 0     | 0      |
| 1    | 0     | 0      |
| 0    | 1     | 0      |
| 1    | 0     | 1      |
| 1    | 0     | 2      |
| 0    | 0     | 2      |
| 1    | 0     | 3      |
| 1    | 0     | 0      |
| 1    | 0     | 1      |
| 1    | 0     | 2      |
| 1    | 1     | 1      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily tackles by `pandas.groupby.transform` and `cumsum`

```
event_cum = df['event'].cumsum()
result = df['cond'].groupby(event_cum).transform('cumsum').mod(4)
result[event_cum == 0] = 0  # rows before the first event
```

> ```
> 0     0
> 1     0
> 2     0
> 3     1
> 4     2
> 5     2
> 6     3
> 7     0
> 8     1
> 9     2
> 10    1
> Name: cond, dtype: int64
> ```

Comment: Really smart & nice solution! Thanks !